# Microsoft SQL, understand transaction locking on low level

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, transactions

I had a weird case when I got a deadlock between a select statement that joined two tables and a transaction that performed multiple updates on those two tables.

I am coming from a Java world, so I thought that using a transaction will lock all the tables in it, but what I come to understand now is that the lock will only be requested when you access the table from your transaction and if someone else is doing a heavy select on that table during that time you might get a deadlock. Just to be fair I also must say that I had multiple connections making that same sequence of calls where they performed a heavy query on two tables and then created a transaction to update those tables, so whatever age case you might think of, there is a big chance I been running into it.

With that been said, can you please provide a low level explanation in what situations you might get a deadlock between a select statement and a transaction?

Comment: Transactions and isolation are two separate concepts.  You need SERIALIZABLE isolation.

Comment: @duffymo I am not familiar with isolation, db serialization, can you please link me so I will understand your comment

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: @duffymo awesome, I got you now!